# Why four tasks named kslowd eat CPU time?

Tags: unity, laptop, performance, cpu-load

I installed Unity on my Belinea o.book 13011. Now there are four Tasks named kslowd000 to kslowd003. Each task uses 10-15% CPU, expect there is another Task that needs more.

So the CPU Fan is running continously. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be [several](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/linux-kernel/2010/6/9/4581247) [bug](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=103382) [reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/595764) [about](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/662946) this in the 2.6.35 kernel (the one that's included in Ubuntu 10.10).

Edit:

These are (some of?) the kernel bugs involved:

- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16265
- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18802
- http://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29536

It seems like there is a workaround, but it doesn't always work (automatically).

You can try to see if the following helps:

```
sudo -c sh "echo N > /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll"
```

Comment: damn, will this be fixed in 10.10?

Comment: I have the bug, but I have no '/sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters' so I cannot try the fix...